# Kivy change background of buttons created with .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy but I am trying to do the following:

I am creating my layout in some .kv files.
Once, a button is pressed, a method in my python code will be executed. This function should then in return change the Color of some buttons.

```
<TabbedPanelHeader>
    background_color: global_background_color_C
    bold: True
    font_size: 16
    on_press: app.create_project()    <--------- The function that is called.

<WindowTabs>
    size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: self.parent.width / 4

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Project'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'data-conversion'      
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'data-source?'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'model'
```

And my python code:

```
class CoreApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CoreWidget()

    def create_project(self):
        >>How to change the color of the buttons here??<<
        return
```

My full code is much more but these are the important lines.
What I got is a tabbed panel and when I click one of the tabs, the Color of all tabs shall change.

Now I've got 2 different ideas but I do not know which one could work and how to implement those:

1. Reference the tabbed panel headers with a variable name and call functions on them with that specific variable name
2. Have a variable in my .kv file that determines the background color of the headers and access that variable in my python code.

Which method is the better one? Is there another method except transfering the .kv code into python code.

I would be very happy if someone could help me :)

Greetings, Finn